# React nativ, aws-amplify storage, getting aws.cognito.identity-id

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, react-native, aws-amplify

i am trying to get aws.cognito.identity-id with React-Native. After successeful sign-in i am getting CognitoUser, but storage variable is equal to [Function MemoryStorage], however with React in my web browser storage has some values. Code in React and React native exactly same.

**Browser output:**

```
...
    storage: Storage
    CognitoIdentityId-eu-central-1:...: "..."
    CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.....LastAuthUser: "..."
    CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.........accessToken: "..."
    CognitoIdentityServiceProvider........clockDrift: "2"
...
```

**Android device output:**

```
...
 "storage": [Function MemoryStorage],
...
```

**Code**

```
Amplify.configure({
     ...awsmobile
});

const client = new AWSAppSyncClient({
     url: awsmobile.aws_appsync_graphqlEndpoint,
     region: awsmobile.aws_appsync_region,
     auth: {
          type: AUTH_TYPE.AWS_IAM,
          credentials: () => Auth.currentCredentials()
     },
});

Auth.signIn(
     'myemail@gmail.com',
     'pass'
)
// .then(user => console.log('user',user))
     .then(user => signInSuccess(user));

function getValueFromKey(myObject, string) {
     const key = Object.keys(myObject).filter(k => k.includes(string));
     return key.length ? myObject[key] : "";
}

function signInSuccess(user) {
     console.log('another', user);
     console.log(getValueFromKey(user.storage, 'aws.cognito.identity-id'))
}

export default class App extends React.Component {
     render() {
          return (
               <Text>nice</Text>
          );
     }
}
```